# Create a "Safe Key" (Selenium C#)

Tags: c#, events, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to have a "Safe Key" in my Selenium test. What I mean by "Safe Key" is an event key which is going to trigger an Exit method whenever it's called during the program execution.

Is there anything already integrated in Selenium which might help me at this, or the only way to do it is to create my own events?

Comment: you could put it into a `Task` and add a cancellation token. this of course would abort the task on completion of the current code method, but would give you a start maybe

Comment: @jimtollan But that is not really something related to Selenium, it's just a way of doing it, please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: correct, it's not directly related to selenium (nor are raising events per se), however, i would contend that it is perhaps a more appropriate gateway inside the .net framework. have a quick look at this little example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191552(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jimtollan Is it automatically interrupting the current process or I have to do it?

Comment: Mystia - that's the $1M question. you can of course use it however you like, either as the result of a condition occurring in your code, or a transistion value or a manual interupt - literally it's a universal option that can be used however you see fit

Comment: @jimtollan Would you please post your reply as an answer, therefore I can mark it as the correct one, hopefully a lot of people will find it useful.

Comment: sure  - tho i felt it was more helpful comment that a full answer. however, will transcribe it over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where perhaps you could use the .net framework inbuilt functionality to achieve a fairly robust solution to your problem.

By using a combination of `Task` and the associated `CancellationToken`, you should be able to control every aspect of the required exit points. A very good example that portrays a scenario that could be similar to your own can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191552(v=vs.110).aspx

In this example, user input keystrokes are awaited and the appropriate action is taken when a defined key is pressed. In your problem domain, this could of course be related to a certain condition being met inside a method, or a transition value from a method being evaluated and the event being raised (and thus the `Task` cancelled). In effect, you'll be able to use the `CancellationToken` and `ManualResetEvent` to party however you feel fit.